# $\{ax^2 + by^2 | x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_p\} = \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

I want to show that for an odd prime $p$ and integers $m,n, \gcd(mn,p) =1$ that:
$$\{mx^2 + ny^2 | x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_p\} = \mathbb{Z}_p$$. I'm thinking about using the fact that there are $(p-1)/2$ quadratic residues and nonresidues in the multiplicative group mod $p$, but I'm not sure how to formalize or proceed.

Comment: There is a confusion about $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Edited, should have both been $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$

Comment: You forgot the title...:)

Answer (score 1):

You presumably want $\cdots=\Bbb Z_p$ where the $\Bbb Z_p$
denotes the integers modulo $p$.

This is a textbook proof. Let $a\in \Bbb Z_p$. One needs to solve
$$mx^2=a-ny^2$$
in $\Bbb Z_p$. Now $mx^2$ takes $\frac12(p+1)$ values as $x$ varies,
and so does $a-ny^2$ as $y$ varies...

Comment: How do you get that $mx^2$ takes $\frac{p+1}{2}$ values?

Comment: @F.Yan Because $x^2$ takes $\frac12(p+1)$ values.

Comment: Oh, so since $m$ is relatively prime to $p$, it permutes each value of $x^2$ to another in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. If $m$ was not relatively prime to $p$, this wouldn't be true correct?

Comment: @F.Yan If $m$ we not relatively prime to $p$ then all the $mx^2$ would be zero in $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't $x^2$ take $\frac{p-1}{2}$ values? And I'm not sure how this solves the problem.

Comment: If $\frac12(p-1)$ is less than $p/2$. If $x^2$ really did only take $\frac12(p-1)$ values, then by the pigeonhole principle there would be some $a$ such that $x^2\equiv a\pmod p$ has at least **three** distinct solutions modulo $p$.

Comment: Ok, so you are counting the 0 element when saying $\frac{(p+1)}{2}$? I don't understand you're last argument using pigeonhole principle, though.